# How can I add UIView object to self.view.window in ios7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'd like to add a dark view layer that covers the whole screen.

In order to do that, I added `UIView` object to window property of `UIViewController` as shown below.I remember I was able to add a view to `window` like this in ios6. But, it doesn't work in ios7.

How am I able to make it work?

Thanks in advance!!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    overlayView.alpha = 0.8;

    [self.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. It adds a view to inside of table view, so it doesn't cover up the navigation bar and tab bar.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Here's one way of doing what you want:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:overlayView];
```

Comment: it run without any error but my view is not showing.

Answer (score 9):

According to the documentation of UIView, the window property is nil if the view has not yet been added to a window which is the case when viewDidLoad is called.

You can do the same thing in `viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;`

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated; {
    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height)];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    overlayView.alpha = 0.8;
    [self.view.window addSubview:overlayView];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 3**

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(overlayView);
```

Answer (score -2):

you can try like this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *overlayView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

    overlayView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    overlayView.alpha = 0.8;
    overlayView.center = self.view.center
    [self.view addSubview:overlayView];
}
```

i hope will helpful for you...